# Optional Parameters into a POST request in .NET?

Tags: .net, post, asp.net-web-api

say that I have a WebApi working over POST and that Api can have 3 parameters

api/login

parameters
-user
-password
-logo(optional)

when I call this api , can I just skip the logo param ?

what is the real meaning to have a optional parameter into a POST type ?
there are mandatory ?

Comment: Do you mean an optional url part? Or the content of the body? Show us your route config and controller method signatures, and clarify what exactly you mean. If something is optional then it's by definition not mandatory...

Comment: in the content of the body.

Comment: I talking about when you are making a request to a webapi , say that webapi have 3 params , my question is , one of them can be a optional parameter, when you are using a POST method?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. In case of POST requests in WebApi you can have only one parameter in the controller method. The body is read once, so if you've got 2 things to read from it, you'll need to wrap them in a complex object, e.g.:

   ```
   class ValuesDto
   {
     public int Value1 {get; set;}
     public string Value2 { get; set;}
   }
   ```

   And the controller method would take the complex object as an argument:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage CreateValues(ValuesDto values) {}
   ```
2. However, the answer to your original question is:

   The whole POST part of the request is not validated by the WebApi when evaluating routes -   only the parameters that the url path consists of are bound at the time when the route is selected. Which means that the POST arguments are optional.

Some links

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/